# "timeout - t" vs. "timeout". Is there any practical difference?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I've been challenging myself to rewrite one of my batch projects using as few characters as possible, and started to wonder if the -t had any purpose at all.

Apparently both scripts below behave in the exact same way when executed.

```
timeout -t 5
echo test
pause
```

```
timeout 5
echo test
pause
```

Both microsoft documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/timeout_1) and ss64 (https://ss64.com/nt/timeout.html) don't mention anything about whether the -t is necessary or not.

Comment: `timeout /?` gives `TIMEOUT [/T] timeout [/NOBREAK]` where the brackets around `[/T]` indicate that it's optional.

Comment: Oh i see. Didn't think about using /? at all. Does it have any function though? Or "timeout -t 5" and "timeout 5" imply the exact same thing?

Comment: I am not aware of any difference between `-t 5` and just `5`.

Comment: as far as I recall, certain windows versions did not yet have the `/t` option, hence it being optional.

Comment: The title might have been a little misleading but what im looking for is to know if “timeout - t” and “timeout” behave differently

Comment: When you type both commands in a cmd prompt, do you visually see any difference?

Comment: @PedrosoFV Another good indication that the switch is optional is that if you enter an invalid time, the error message is the same with or without `/t`, and references `/t` in both cases: `ERROR: Invalid value for timeout (/T) specified. Valid range is -1 to 99999.`. I believe the first versions of `timeout` from the *Microsoft Windows NT Server 4.0 Resource Kit* did not use `/t` so it's a matter of backwards compatibility, but I don't have an authoritative source handy to quote on that.

Comment: @dxiv Thank you! I didn't see that when testing for differences. Could you post your previous comment as an answer so I can mark the question as solved?

Comment: @PedrosoFV Done, found and added a historical reference as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `timeout` command's own `/?` help shows `[/T]` in a bracket, indicating that it's optional.

```
C:\>timeout /?

TIMEOUT [/T] timeout [/NOBREAK]

Description:
    This utility accepts a timeout parameter to wait for the specified
    time period (in seconds) or until any key is pressed. It also
    accepts a parameter to ignore the key press.
...
```

The error message displayed when given an invalid parameter also mentions `/T` regardless of whether it was actually specified on the command line or not.

```
C:\>timeout ***
ERROR: Invalid value for timeout (/T) specified. Valid range is -1 to 99999.
```

The `/T` switch being optional is probably done for backwards compatiblity, since the early versions of `timeout` released with the NT4/2000 resource kits did not have `/T` as a switch. For example, this is the `timeout.exe` from the *Windows 2000 Server Resource Kit Supplement 1*.

```
C:\>dir C:\etc\*.exe | find /i "timeout"
12/02/1999  03:54 PM            62,464 TIMEOUT.EXE

C:\>C:\etc\timeout /?

TIMEOUT - This utility is similar to the DOS PAUSE command.  However, it
          accepts a timeout parameter to specify a length of wait (in seconds)
          at which time it will continue without a key press.

          Written by Eric Brown, Business System Division.
          Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation, 1992-1995.

Usage -   TIMEOUT <###>
          where <###> is a decimal number of seconds between -1 and 100000.
          The value -1 means to wait indefinitely for a key hit.
```